# ROS Answers SE migration: rqt_shell tmux

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for the contribution of rqt_shell. I am implementing a GUI in ROS indigo, Ubuntu 14.4. However, the integrated rqt_shell cannot use 'tmux' functionality by right clicking and adding a tag, like Guake. Could you please tell me how to implement the terminal multiplexer functionality in rqt_shell plug in? Thank you.

I look forward to your reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246624/rqt_shell-tmux/) by [Helen HOU](https://answers.ros.org/users/28362/helen-hou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems you already reported this over at [ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins#404](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/404).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0